# Get moment object from locale date string

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am creating a validation for an input to check if the given value is a valid date. The input is a dutch string in a specific format. I want to get a `moment.js object` from this string. For example: 'maandag 18 december 2017'. I tried

```
moment('maandag 18 december 2017', 'dddd DD MMMM YYYY');
```

but it returns an `moment` object saying that it is an invalid date. How can i specify the locale given in the string to check?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually set the locale to Dutch

```
moment.locale('nl');
```

then you can do

```
var date = moment('maandag 18 december 2017', 'dddd DD MMMM YYYY')

console.log(date.format):

// outputs "2017-12-18T00:00:00+00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment is giving support for dutch. Have a look in  [moments page](https://momentjs.com/)

Should be something like:

```
moment(<string date>).format('LLLL');
```

or

```
moment(<string date>, 'LLLL');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation about moment.js internationalization: [*Moment.js i18n*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/)

You should use from [their website](https://momentjs.com/) the file [*moment-with-locales.js*](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js) and then use the Dutch locale as mentionned in the doc:

```
moment.locale('nl'),
```

JSFiddle example about locale: http://jsfiddle.net/d8f4gcdL/